# Telegram BOT - masking passwords and changing text color

Tags: html, api, go, telegram

I have a telegram bot communicating with my app built in golang
I scoured through this resource but cant find anywhere where it mentions changing text colors or masking things such as passwords
It did however mention using html formatting but I have been unsucessful
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#formatting-options
I am hoping someone with some Telegram api experience will read this and know exactly what I am referring to and shed some light on whether it can or cannot be done

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, it can not be done.

Telegram Bot Api has a limited set of formating options.
Changing text color and masking passwords is not one of them.

All what is available can be found at the link you mentioned.